# Using URL Rewrite to redirect a link

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

i have trouble in case i have a link like this.
agdashboard.graphia.co.id/.but cannot access and showing IIS Windows Server.And I want when people access that link, the url link redirecting to agdashboard.graphia.co.id/MicroStrategy/asp/Main.aspx so people can access the dashboard.

What must i do for this?

Thanks before

when access url agdashboard.graphia.co.id/ and redirect to agdashboard.graphia.co.id/MicroStrategy/asp/Main.aspx

Comment: Learn how to use IIS URL rewrite module, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module That's something trivial and you usually don't need anyone else to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use url rewrite, this rule you can use as a reference:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^agdashboard.graphia.co.id$" />
          </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="agdashboard.graphia.co.id/MicroStrategy/asp/Main.aspx" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```